# List connections in use of a JDBC Data Source

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection, jndi

How do i list all connections that are in use?

This is my code:

```
        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();


        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup("jdbc/xxxxxx");
        con = dataSource.getConnection();
```

So, having this, i want to list all connections that are currently been used to monitor the system and if needed, close the connections.

Comment: Generally you can't: there is nothing in the `DataSource` API that exposes this kind of information. What data source are you using?

Comment: javax.sql.DataSource

Comment: That is an interface, not an actual implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a util wrapper where `getConnection()` will increment and `returnConection` will decrement. You can use connection pool like dbcp which has `BasicDataSource` has method   `getNumIdle()` and `getNumActive()` for this kind of matrics